Represent vector as sum of two orthogonal ones
I am trying to validate the following statement:
Let $a$ be a vector in the vector space $V$.
Is it true that for a given vector $v$ I can always represent $a=v+b$ where $v^Tb = 0$?
I deducted this from this website here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-proof-that-every-vector-can-be-expressed-as-the-sum-of-its-orthogonal-components
Though I am

not sure if the theorem is valid since I cannot find it anywhere
I am not sure if my reformulation with  for a given vector $v$ I can find $b$ in its orthogonal complement" is correct.

I think this question here $\vec{y}$ as the sum of two orthogonal vectors goes in the same direction.

It should be $a=x v + b$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$, that is $xv$ is a scaled version of $v$. In other words, you take a component from the subspace of $V$ generated by $v$ and a component from the orthogonal subspace, as explained in the Quora post. Search for "orthogonal decomposition" if you need more details.

Not every vector space has elements that are ordered pairs or triples or whatever of numbers.
